# Titanium appcelerator sqlite saving a lastInsertRowId to a global variable

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

How can I go about saving `lastInsertRowId` to a global variable that I can access later to UPDATE a column in my database? I know I am only able to access `lastInsertRowId` at the point of trigger, but how can I save that and be able to access it in another location in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use following of 2 options :

- Save it using : `Ti.App.Properties.setInt('lastInsertRowId', value);` and fetch it using `Ti.App.Properties.getInt('lastInsertRowId');`Using this will make this value persistence ( means value will be available whenever app is launched ).
- Save it using Alloy Globals ( only available for the current session of app)

  ```
  Alloy.Globals.lastInsertRowId= value; //set
  var value = Alloy.Globals.lastInsertRowId; //get
  ```